# Can I(and if yes, how) Copy Windows 10 Home or/and Pro to Bootable Flash Drive

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation

I want to buy Windows 10(home or pro, not sure yet) and a laptop without CD Drive and be able to install(when needed) Windows 10, but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to copy Windows 10 to Flash Drive and how to do so(there's probably some copy-prevention security etc) it would have boot option in it.

Can anyone please help me to answer this questions from your knowledge/experience or by directing me for some other source?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 is available as a download from Microsoft. You can install it and then you are expected to license it on the computer you are running. Licenses are tied to the hardware it runs on, not necessarily the disk drive it was installed to.

You would need at least a 32 Gb flash drive. Windows 10 won't fit on a 16gb drive.  You'll also a USB for the installer. Usually an 8Gb one will do (although with WinToUSB, link below, you may not need both)

You would first need the installer on a flash drive, which is a simple process, and then you would need to boot from that drive and install it on another flash drive so that you could boot into the full running windows.

Windows 10 Media Creation Tool was most recently here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 may resist being installed onto a USB drive. The simplest way around that is the to use the tool called WinToUsb. This was recently available here:
https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/